# Create .desktop file as shorcut to a folder in Lubuntu LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, directory, shortcuts, lxde

What is the "Exec=" part of a desktop configuration file for this? I guess I should mention file manager but how exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

Exec=filemanager /path/to/folder

On the desktop (that is: in pcmanfm) right click

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The option to create a shortcut does not appear for me in Lubuntu 15.10 so I used the following command line:

> ln -s /path/to/folder ~/Desktop

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem!

The solution for me was to create a new file on desktop, open it with leafpad and write the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Myname
Exec=pcmanfm /home/myfolder
Icon=/home/iconpath
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Save it and you will have a shortcut to /home/myfolder